# Need magento store id using store name

Tags: magento, web, store

I want to get the Magento Store id using Store Name as Search.

I tried below code but failed.

```
$vendortitle = $vendortitle . " Store";
$name = Mage::getModel('core/store')->load($vendortitle)->getStoreId();
echo "<br>Store Name> ". $name;
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean store code? If so try this:

```
echo Mage::app()->getStore()->getCode(); // gives 'default'
// then use the following to get the store id
echo Mage::app()->getStore('default')->getId();
```